# Create font awesome icons without content

Tags: wordpress, font-awesome

I want to use font-awesome icons without using content. Let's say I want to use the linked in icon:

When I save this into a text-editor in Wordpress, it disappears, when I refresh the site. Why?
It only shows, when I put content next or before the icon. But I want to use it without content. Just like in the attached image. [click here to see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XB2q.png)

How can I do this? When I wrap it into a-tag it still disappears: `<a href="your link here"> <i class="fab fa-linkedin-in"></i></a>`

Please help!

Comment: This is happening because Wordpress is removing the "empty" element. You'll need to look at the WP editor. BTW, did my other answer work for you or do you need more help.

Comment: Hi Thanks for your kind response. And yes this is what I mean. The editor delets it. But how can I fix that? What do I have to do? :(